# A manager's dilemma

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, story

> A sports manager was walking nervously on the street. It was a stressful time for him and he didn't know what to do. Two of their biggest stars had drunkenly trashed another hotel room after a visiting game. Their antics were all over the news. Again. And every time they made the headlines, the team name was of course mentioned prominently as well. He had given the players warning after warning, and every time they promised to be on their best behaviour.
>
> Ticket sales were at a ten-year low. Sponsors were jumping ship after a long period of disappointing results in addition to the constant negative publicity. There were no solutions in sight that would make everyone happy. He would have to make some tough decisions, and he would have to make them soon.
>
> As he was walking, he noticed an abandoned warehouse burning in the distance. He walked closer. He could hear sirens approaching; the Newark fire department was surely already on the way. The building was engulfed in flames. The roof and walls were on the verge of collapse. He saw the flames rise high up in the sky in majestic whirls, again and again. He watched, mesmerized by the sight.
>
> As he walked back to his office, he was suddenly sure what he needed to do.

What did the manager decide? What helped him reach his decision?

---

<sub>This puzzle is part of *[Recycling old answers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81150)*.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He decided he needed to

> Fire Devils?

Because:

> If we are talking about Newark, NJ, we can assume the team is the New Jersey Devils

He saw:

> A vortex of flame, which could be described as a 'Fire Devil' (in the same vein as a *Dust Devil*)
>  So, it seems some of the team members lost their job that day